# Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I am trying to enumerate group members from Google Apps Script using the following code:

```
AdminDirectory.Groups.get("scouts@troop1313.com")
```

and getting this message

> Access Not Configured. The API (Admin Directory API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration. (line 65, file "Code")

I already authorized the script/project by running it directly from the online IDE but that did not help.

The project key is `Mcdd3jWb8x_CBgWbrqpOo7WzCrlavxzZ2` and the function I am calling is `getFolderContents`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a head up, **Admin Directory API** renamed to **Admin SDK** on API Manager.

Find that API and enable it helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For advanced Google API's like the Admin Directory service you need to enable the service within your Google account's "developer console".

This authorisation is required in addition to the stock Apps Script authorization dialogues you mention in your question.

See the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services

Comment: Thanks Cameron.  I did not realize that setting was PER PROJECT since I had already set it in a different project.  Once I did that (by clicking on the link at the bottom of the Admin SDK permissions screen) I was good to go!